# The geometric distribution - How many trials occur before we obtain a success doubt

Tags: probability, geometric-series, bernoulli-numbers

I have doubts on the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455920/calculating-the-expectation-of-a-geometric-distribution)

First, What is `k` here?

Second, I know E[X]= E[I{A}], `I` define indicator random variable. We can say that I{A} is the indicator random variable of geometric distribution. Now, I{A} depend upon probability of success and failure. So I{A} = 1.pr{Success} + 0. pr{failure}. However, from the 1st line of derivation I cannot understand where 1.pr{Success} + 0. pr{failure} is used.

3rd, from where we appear in the 3rd line of the calculation?

if it is coming from geometric summation then the geometric summation for infinite series is

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$

Then It should be $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right)$$

Comment: Perhaps easier to just think about the first trial.  It's either a success (and the game stops) or a failure and the game resets (with expectation increased by $1$).  Thus $E=1+(1-p)E\implies E=\frac 1p$.

Comment: A geometric distribution is a random variable that can have any non-negative integer value. It is not an event that either does or does not occur. An indicator variable $I_A$ requires $A$ to be an event. It makes no sense to speak of the "indicator random variable of geometric distribution." I think you need first to review the definition of a geometric random variable carefully, without assuming you know anything about it, because it seems some of the things you think you "know" are not correct.

Comment: ok, Can you please tell me  from where we appear in the 3rd line of the calculation? You need to follow the link that I have provided.